# Office Fabric UI I[component]StyleProp vs I[component]Styles interface use

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint, web-parts, office-ui-fabric

In the Office Fabric UI documentation every component has two interfaces, for example

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/nav

has

INavStyleProps interface

and

INavStyles interface

a component implementing INavStyleProps can take in any of the listed props to customize style, for example

I am wondering if there is any way to interact with INavStyles classes exposed through the documentation; essentially what does implementing the INavStyles interface guarantee to the consumer of the component, other than the listed classes and styles are implemented. Is there a way to override, customize, or otherwise interact with the classes exposed through this interface similar to how we can use props to interact with components implementing INavStylesProps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/Nav/Nav.styles.ts#L38-L250) showing the use of both interfaces for Nav. It's a how we give to Nav the default styles.

In order to override the default styles for any `INavStyles` [area](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/Nav/Nav.types.ts#L310-L363), you can use the [`styles`](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/Nav/Nav.types.ts#L27) prop and pass to it a styleFunctionOrObject. As you can see from the first link provided, `INavStyleProps` are used to pass some values to be used in the styling of the parts of the `Nav` or booleans to have some conditional styling. Also, that is how we pass the theme to the styles.

A style function you can pass to `styles` prop would look exactly as the one we use to provide the default styles minus the `getGloballClassNames`. Also if you want to style just one area the return type should be `Partial<INavStyles>` as all areas are required and it will complain if you don't provides styles for all of them.

Let me know if this cleared the confusion on how to make use of both interfaces.

Comment: I came across this solution in the sharepoint documentation eventually and it works. However you have to represent the styles as JSON objects and they suggest storing these as css.js files. Is this the best approach in your opinion or is there a better way to integrate through the sharepoint tools, similarly to how they convert the sass files to js objects under the hood when you import.

Comment: I think a better naming would be style objects, rather than JSON. When you say storing, you mean where the style object is written de facto? Also, could you give me a link to the SharePoint documentation you found?